# UINavigationBar dims down when entering search

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios11, uinavigationitem, uisearchcontroller

I've made an empty view controller wrapped in a navigation controller, and added a search bar using the `navigationItem.searchController`. A weird thing though, when tapping the search bar the animation works well but the navigation bar dims down as the entire screen.

This is NOT how it works on Settings and other places, i.e. the color of the navigation bar should stay the same.

Any ideas?

Some code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UISearchController* searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set `dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation` or `obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation` to `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

In your viewDidLoad method, add:

```
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```